# Docker-compose caches my password for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, caching, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup my mongodb and with docker. I created a docker-compose file

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports: ["27017:27017"]
    env_file: [".env"]
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks: ["some_network"]
    volumes: [./mongo-volume:/data/db]

volumes: 
  mongo-volume:

networks:
  some_network:
    driver: bridge
```

In my .env I did define my variables:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=hMSZ7!dM!@HA&EF6
```

Because I'd like to use MongoCompass and had some problems with the '@' I had to change the password, simply removed the '@'.

But I still can not got a connection. Instead I try to use mongo-client and used the old password, well it worked. But I'll like to change my password. I already used docker-compose down and remove the volume and the image. But it is still cached somewhere. Also I logged in to the container and echo the password, this will be the new one.

Additional information:
I use docker on windows with wsl (Ubuntu)
With this I watched through the directory /var/lib/docker/volumes/ what I found was nothing. I guess. on wsl the volumes are mount somewhere else...
So I changed the mount point, and my new password would be accepted.
But where are my volume mounted?

Comment: I suspect mongo rather than docker. As you said, your old password works when you connect vi's client, then password might not be changed at mongo server.

Comment: The `*_INITDB_*` variables only get processed when the database is first initialized; after that these credentials are stored in the database data volume.  The linked question describes how to do it without `volumes:`; given the setup you show, if you want the Docker initialization to happen, you need to delete the `mongo-volume` directory on the host and then re-run `docker-compose up`.